# Changing the signs in the metric and the curvature

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, semi-riemannian-geometry

Suppose we have two Riemannian manifolds $(B,g_B)$ and $(F,g_F)$ and consider their product $C:=B\times F$ endowed with the metric tensor $g_C:=-\pi_B^*(g_B)+\pi_F^*(g_F)$, where $\pi_B$ and $\pi_F$ denote the projections on $B$ and $F$ respectively and $^*$ is the pullback.

If I want to write the Ricci tensor of $C$, if $g$ was the usual product metric then that tensor would be just the sum of the two Ricci's on $B$ and $F$, but in this case the sign $-$ in front of $\pi_B^*(g_B)$ should change the sign of the Ricci of $B$: if $\xi:=x+v$, where $x\in T_bB$ and $v\in T_fF$ for $b\in B$ and $f\in F$, I would have$$\textrm{Ric}_{(b,f)}^C(\xi,\xi)=-\textrm{Ric}^B_b(x,x)+\textrm{Ric}^F_f(v,v).$$

What confuses me is the fact that if I change the sign in a metric of a Riemannian manifold the curvature tensors do not change (since the Riemann tensor is made of Christoffel symbols in coordinates which are products of the matrices of the metric) but here the Ricci does. Does this come from the fact that the metric contraction wrt the $g_C$?

If I have a smooth function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ than the Hessian of $f$ would be the same of $B$ but with the same sign?

P.s. I did everything not in coordinates, using, given a frame $\{E_i\}_i$ on $C$,$$\textrm{Ric}^C(X,Y)=\sum_ig_C(E_i,E_i)\,g_C(\textrm{R}^C_{XE_i}Y,E_i),$$following O'Neill computations in chapter $7$ of his book "Semi-Riemannian geometry".

Comment: How do you obtain the first formula? The $(0,2)$ Ricci tensor is obtained from the $(1,3)$ Riemann tensor without involving the metric, so if the the former shouldn't depend on the sign of the metric any more than the latter.

Comment: I just used the formula below (also in O'Neill, Lemma $3.52$), assuming to be able to write every $E_i$ as $E_j+E_k$, where $E_j$ and $E_k$ are frames on $B$ and $F$ and using $[X,V]=0$ if $X, V$ are vector fields on $B, F$ respectively.
It must also follow from the formulas $(1)-(3)$ of Proposition $7.43$ in the same book, assuming the warping function to be $1$. I repeat, it follows if I can write $\xi=x+v$

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're doing with the frames, but the formulae you cite shouldn't lead to a minus sign. Notice the metric $g_C$ appears twice in the formula for $\operatorname{Ric}^C$, so reversing the sign of the metric should have no effect. One can eliminate the metric entirely using the slight modification$$\operatorname{Ric}(X,Y)=\sum_i\hat{E}^i(R_{X,Y}E_i$$where $\hat{E}^i$ is the coframe dual to $E_i$.